# Adding Action Listeners at Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, actionlistener

I have a Jbutton added on a frame automaticaly by netbeans.
I want to add this Actionlistener to a button.

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"hello");
}
```

My problem is that when I add this code

```
  jButton2.addActionListener(MyActionListener);
```

in order to add the listener to the button I get a "non-static variable jButton2 cannot be referenced from a static context" message.
Since jButton2 is automatically created by netbeans as non static, how can overcome this problem and set the actionlistener as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in that you are sending an object that has never been instantiated. When you add an action listener to any component you need to send an object that implements the ActionListener interface. Is like adding an instance of the listener to the object.
try this:

```
jButton2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

if you want to use an Anonymous implementation then you will do:

```
jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   //some code
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! jButton2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener()); solved it

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to add a listener is just to right-click on the button from the design view, select

```
Events -> Action -> actionPerformed
```

and the code will be auto-generated for you

```
public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // put what you want to happen, here
}
```